# How to see who was present in a meeting on Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How to see who was present in a meeting on Outlook. I have a meeting with 10 people who accepted the meeting but not all of them join the meeting. Is there a way I can check who was present at a certain meeting later (2 weeks after the meeting)?

Answer (score 0):

In Teams, go to Calendar
open the meeting
and select the Attendance tab.

You can view the data directly in Teams:

[image: Attendees List Option Image]

To download the attendance .CSV file for the meeting, click Download:

[image: download option image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can check who was present at a certain meeting later
> (2 weeks after the meeting)?

Generally, no.  If people accepted the meeting, you cannot know two weeks later if they attended or not.

If a video meeting, Zoom or Teams, you would need to check at the time of the meeting. Even for this, unless you make a record, you cannot know two weeks later.

As you have posed the question, short answer is: no.